# Magento 2 - Rename Sort by option label

Tags: magento2

I need to rename the options in the Sort By dropdown on catalog listing page, i.e. 'Product Name' and 'Price'.
Please guide how can I achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use product attributes.

Go to admin, from store->under attributes click on Product.
There search for `Price`. You can see there is one with `Filterable (with results)` under its `Use in Layered Navigation`.

Click on the attribute to open and then from the left menu click on `Manage labels`. In the field type your required label assigned to you shop. Save and then flush the cache.
Your new label should be there in storefront category in sorter.

[image]

Comment: Can the 'Position' label be changed through same steps ?

Comment: Yes @user54226 yo ucan also rename position with same technique.

Comment: I couldn't find Position in Attributes > Product, what I'm missng...